# Cupertino-style pane web component that you can slide to any height you want

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile, pane

I am currently working on a mobile app using the Ionic Framework and Angular. I need a cupertino-style pane that, instead of having specific breakpoints you can slide it to, instead allows you to slide it to any position you want. I tried looking for a pre-existing library providing this functionality, but I could not find one. The closest I found was https://github.com/roman-rr/cupertino-pane. The third image in the READEME illustrates pretty much what I want, except that again, I want to be able to stop the pane at any height I want, and it doesn't seem to me that that library supports that.

Would anyone know if there is a pre-existing library that provides what I'm looking for? I feel like it would be quite difficult to implement from scratch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cupertion pane is a good choice. I think you can achieve your goal by using `freeMode` param. Check it in the [documentation](https://github.com/roman-rr/cupertino-pane#settings).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that property before, but that did the trick.

Comment: @Nexus Great! Can you accept my answer in this way?